# Ruby: How to open .exe file(that open CMD) and run command init

Tags: ruby, cmd

I am trying using ruby script to a task.
I have an .exe file that i want to run.
when opening this file it open in CMD and i can pass commands to it.
That file located in C:\temp\test.exe
I need to go to the directory and then open the file and then insert to it command like:
"getobject" task = "aa"
this program will give me the result to the CMD.
i will need to copy the result to text but i think i can handle it late.

I tried to search it online cant found anything.

Thanks

Comment: question is not clear, you want to run .exe from your ruby code and collect the output, is that what you want?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, @omri hamo. This is probably not the answer you wanted to see ... But, here at stackoverflow, we want to see you try to find a solution yourself first. Subsequently, the community is here to help you. Go ahead and try something and if you get stuck, ask a  question, show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: I want to run .exe from ruby, then the .exe we just ran open cmd window. in this cmd window i want to pass some commands, this commands will print some data in the cmd window. i want to collect this data to txt.                Thanks

Comment: Did you write the .exe - in other words - can you allow your exe to accept the commands as arguments instead of being typed after run ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open an executable, usually you can use the `command` syntax in Ruby. So call:

```
`C:\temp\test.exe`
```

That should run the executable from the Ruby script. Then you can interact with that executable as if you ran it from a CMD instead of a Ruby file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run and capture the output of a command you'll need to use a system command. There are many system commands that you can use, but my preference is [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html):

```
require 'open3'
output, status = Open3.capture2("C:\temp\test.exe")
```

In the event that you want to pass command line arguments to `capture2` you'll want to write that like this: `Open3.capture2("C:\temp\test.exe", "arg1", "arg2")`. [That is the safest way to pass arguments.](http://gavinmiller.io/2015/fixing-command-injection-vulnerabilities/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is input/ output redirection

check [redirection](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Not tested
`system 'C:\temp\test.exe < "\"getobject\" task = \"aa\""'`